# Issue with an update on fedora 32

Tags: fedora

I have fedora 32 on a computer with multiple accounts. I got a message for some OS updates, firefox and libre office. I clicked on install. The computer restarted. Now it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K0Cq.jpg), when I try to enter, then it gives me a black screen. I don't know how to fix it, because I can't even access the terminal. I suppose I need to rollback those updates. But I have no idea how to do it. Maybe from grub(?) I'd appreciate any help.

For instance, [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/manual-rollbacks/) they suggest logging into the target node and running `rpm-ostree rollback -r`. Is the target node the same as grub? or how can I access that target node?

I just checked. I had enabled ssh. So, I can access the terminal via ssh from another computer. What I just noticed is that `rpm-ostree rollback -r` says: Command not found. What this suggests then is that problem is with the graphical interface. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to sort that out.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Edit 1:

I have recorded this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1912suCUlhRwU2e8OnI-7Lqn7_BdnQhCt/view?usp=sharing) (let me know if you can see it) showing exactly what I see.
I can access the terminal via ssh. Everything seems to be working. So, I suppose the problem is the graphical interface.

Comment: Try booting into an older kernel. To access a text console you need to press Ctrl + Alt + F2-F6. F1 is where your X.org server runs by default. Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 will net you nothing if you're stuck at the graphical login manager.

Comment: Please describe exactly what happens after GRUB has started loading the kernel. You might want to press Escape as soon as the kernel gets loaded - this way a boot process will be verbose. You may even record a video and post it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what the problem was [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/hr7u1z/black_screen_on_booting_after_update/). I am sharing in case it's useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

From: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/manual-rollbacks/

## "Manual Rollbacks

When an update is complete, the previous OS deployment remains on disk. If an update causes issues, you can use it as a fallback. This is a manual operation that requires human intervention and console access."

## Fix

What I just quoted to you now is from the same page you linked. You need to access tty1, as I understand it. You can do that with the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I didn't see that you knew you needed access to the terminal. I guess the quote I gave at the top wasn't necessary.

Edit 2: Artem gives a good idea about trying to boot into an older kernel. Looking at images of Fedora's GRUB2, it looks like there are options to do that on GRUB. If it doesn't show up, there should be an 'Advanced Options' menu, where you can boot into different kernel versions. I found an image of what Fedora's GRUB might look like WITHOUT an 'Advanced Options' menu

[image: Fedora GRUB Menu]

Edit 3: **If it seems that entering commands to do a permanent rollback doesn't work, you may have to, for the time being, do a temporary one. According to Fedora's documentation, it says to hold `shift` during the boot process. Then there will be several entries and you need to choose the right one.**

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 didn't work. Or when should I use the shortcut?

Comment: After the GRUB prompt. Enter Fedora, and then use that shortcut. I hope it works now.

Comment: I can't enter Fedora. When I try to enter, I just get a black screen.

Comment: Have you tried the shortcut when you get to that black screen?

Comment: Yes, it does nothing. Let me try to add pictures to better show what I see.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov suggests trying Ctrl+Alt+F2. Try that.

Comment: Ctral+Alt+F2 also does nothing. :(

Comment: @frosbyte, where can I access that "Advanced Options" menu?

Comment: If it exists at all, it would be in GRUB under your Fedora. If it doesn't appear, there should be multiple versions of Fedora right in front of you. If so, look for the one with the older kernel version and select that.